# Sign Up button in Single post type page

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have a Custom post type named 'Services' and in that i have Service 1, Service 2, Service 3, Service 4. Each service has a sign up button. When clicking on the the sign up button, it shows different sign up forms for each services. I am using wordpress. How can I do this? Please help me.

Comment: Create four forms with a form plugin of your choice and include them.

Comment: @cgee... I have created four forms using contact form 7 plugin. But i don't know how to include them. Can you please instruct me? Thanks

Comment: Sry I use formidable.. But I think contact form 7 use shortcodes to include forms. Like this: [contact-form-7 id="186" title="Main Contact Form"] if you want to include your forms into a template you can do it with this code: <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="186" title="Main Contact Form"]'); ?>